# Trying to construct a greedy algorithm with python

Tags: python

So i'm trying to create a greedy algorithm for a knapsack problem. The txt file below is the knap20.txt file.  The first line gives the number of items, in this case 20. The last line gives the capacity of the knapsack, in this case 524. The remaining lines give the index, value and weight of each item.

My function is to ideally return the solution in a list and the value of the weights

From what I can tell by my results, my program is working correctly. Is it working as you would expect, and how can i improve it?

txt file

```
20
    1    91    29
    2    60    65
    3    61    71
    4     9    60
    5    79    45
    6    46    71
    7    19    22
    8    57    97
    9     8     6
   10    84    91
   11    20    57
   12    72    60
   13    32    49
   14    31    89
   15    28     2
   16    81    30
   17    55    90
   18    43    25
   19   100    82
   20    27    19
524
```

python file

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values):
    value = 0.
    numItems = len(values)
    valuePerWeight = sorted([[values[i] / weights[i], weights[i]] for i in range(numItems)], reverse=True)
    while capacity > 0 and numItems > 0:
        maxi = 0
        idx = None
        for i in range(numItems):
            if valuePerWeight[i][1] > 0 and maxi < valuePerWeight[i][0]:
                maxi = valuePerWeight[i][0]
                idx = i

        if idx is None:
            return 0.
        if valuePerWeight[idx][1] <= capacity:
            value += valuePerWeight[idx][0]*valuePerWeight[idx][1]
            capacity -= valuePerWeight[idx][1]
        else:
            if valuePerWeight[idx][1] > 0:
                value += (capacity / valuePerWeight[idx][1]) * valuePerWeight[idx][1] * valuePerWeight[idx][0]
                return values, value
        valuePerWeight.pop(idx)
        numItems -= 1
    return value


def read_kfile(fname):
    print('file started')
    with open(fname) as kfile:
        print('fname found', fname)
        lines = kfile.readlines()     # reads the whole file
    n = int(lines[0])
    c = int(lines[n+1])
    vs = []
    ws = []
    lines = lines[1:n+1]   # Removes the first and last line
    for l in lines:
        numbers = l.split()   # Converts the string into a list
        vs.append(int(numbers[1]))  # Appends value, need to convert to int
        ws.append(int(numbers[2]))  # Appends weigth, need to convert to int
    return n, c, vs, ws

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))  # Get the directory where the file is located
os.chdir(dir_path)  # Change the working directory so we can read the file


knapfile = 'knap20.txt'
nitems, capacity, values, weights = read_kfile(knapfile)
val1,val2 = get_optimal_value(capacity, weights, values)
print ('values',val1)
print('value',val2)
```

result

```
values [91, 60, 61, 9, 79, 46, 19, 57, 8, 84, 20, 72, 32, 31, 28, 81, 55, 43, 100, 27]
value 733.2394366197183
```

Comment: You should update your question so it actually contain a question. Right now it's just a statement.

Comment: This might be better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).